# Content Security Policy in Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, manifest, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

My Chrome app has the following manifest:

```
{
    "name": ",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Chrome Extension for.",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/test.png",
        "19": "images/test.png",
        "256": "images/test.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": [
                "background.js"
            ]
        }
    },

    "sandbox": {
        "js": [
            "lib/test-api.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "notifications",
        "storage",
        "videoCapture"
    ]
}
```

I have a script file that runs `eval`. I have read about [CSP](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) and sandboxing, but I still get this error:

> Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is
>   not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
>   Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is
>   used as a fallback.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Have you tried adding the CSP line to your manifest as per your [CSP](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-eval) link?

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: Yes but i use app package app

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understand exactly...  From reading about [packaged apps](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/articles/apps_vs_extensions?csw=1) it looks like that shouldn't matter.  Is your eval in the background.js, the test-api.js, or both?

Comment: @brucek I think the error he's referring to is '`content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.'` In apps, you'll need to  use sandboxing to use eval. See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: Yep thx, I figured that out eventually ;-)  @rob-w has the answer below

Comment: Presumably there is a reason why this is a "bad thing".

Answer (score 36):

What you're showing is **not** a [Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html), but a [Chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html).
**Chrome extensions will let you relax the default Content Security Policy; Chrome Apps won’t.** (source: [CSP docs for Chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html#what); note: this page is different from [CSP docs for Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)).

The next line applies to apps and extensions:

- The Content security policy does not apply to a specific script, but a whole page. So, you can only declare a sandbox for a whole page (using the [`sandbox.pages` key in the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox.html)). You **cannot** use "js" as a key in sandbox.

In a Chrome extension, the CSP can be relaxed, e.g. allowing `eval` using the following policy:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

**To turn your app in an extension**: Do not use the `apps` key, but use a `background` key. With the following manifest, you'll be able to use `eval` in your background page:

```
{
    "name": "Whatever",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

(omitted `icons` / `permissions` because they're not relevant for the example; omitted `sandbox` because it's not needed)