# Chrome app content security policy not leting to run eval() even after made changes in manifest.json

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

I'm developing a Chrome App with **Google Blockly**. In order to run JavaScript code dynamically I want to use `eval()` function.

---

[Chrome app relaxing the default policy using manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-eval)

I tried the above link. I used this manifest as suggested by chrome docs.

---

### manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Blockly",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "46",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

---

### inject.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
 document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let code = 'initiate();';
  try {
    eval(code);
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e); 
  }
 });
});
```

---

I am still getting this error :

> EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
> 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob:
> filesystem: 'wasm-eval'".
>
> at HTMLButtonElement. (inject.js:40)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047150/refused-to-evaluate-a-string-as-javascript-because-unsafe-eval-is-not-an-allow)

Comment: Also [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/a/25721457)

Comment: This one answered my question [content-security-policy-in-chrome-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130400/content-security-policy-in-chrome-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I found answer

[Content Security Policy in Chrome App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130400/content-security-policy-in-chrome-app)

**Chrome extensions will let you relax the default Content Security Policy; Chrome Apps won’t.**