# How to update the Content Security Policy in a Chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome-app, content-security-policy, manifest.json

I see in [Chrome's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy) that the content security policies for Chrome Apps can't be relaxed. However, I'm wondering: can the content security policy be updated to make it more restrictive? If so how is that done?

The [manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) for Chome Apps does not include a field for `content_security_policy` like the [manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) for extensions does.

Comment: There's no way to use content_security_policy but maybe it'll process the `meta` tags in html e.g . `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="....">`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Content Security Policy in Chrome App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130400/content-security-policy-in-chrome-app) - looks like you can/should use sandboxing.

Comment: @wOxxOm that SO question looks more relevant to Chrome extensions and less relevant to Chrome apps. I like the idea of putting the CSP in a meta tag - I might try that out. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Eh? That topic describes all of the options. Except the meta tag, which I haven't tried.